# Two Verbatims (fancyvrb) side by side with frame and uncovering lines

Tags: beamer, minipage, fancyvrb, fbox

I'm wondering if there is a possibility to create in beamer two `Verbatim` environments side by side, each with the frame of the width of `\textwidth` and with gradually uncovering lines.

More specifically:

1. I use `minipage` to create two `Verbatim` environments. However, I'm not able to create frame with fixed width. I tried `\fbox{}` for `minipage` but once `Verbatim` is in `minipage` it does not work. With an option `frame=single` for `Verbatim`, the frame is displayed but it is only around the code.
2. I would like to uncover some lines gradually in both `minipages`. `\only` and `\uncover` seem to not work with `Verbatim`. I used `\begin{onlyenv} \end{onlyenv}` instead, it works fine, but not sure how will it deal with possible frame.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, t]{beamer}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile, plain]
%\fbox{ % this does not work
\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{onlyenv}<1->
    \begin{Verbatim}
Some code here 1a
    \end{Verbatim}
\end{onlyenv}
\begin{onlyenv}<3->
    \begin{Verbatim}
Some code here 1b
    \end{Verbatim}
\end{onlyenv}   
\end{minipage}
%}
%\fbox{ % this does not work
\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{0.54\textwidth}
\begin{onlyenv}<2->
    \begin{Verbatim}
Some code here 2a
    \end{Verbatim}
\end{onlyenv}   
\begin{onlyenv}<4->
    \begin{Verbatim}
Some code here 2b
    \end{Verbatim}
\end{onlyenv}   
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
%}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example only contains code.  What else do what inside the frame?

Comment: Maybe some figures. Everything should be inside the frame.

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236339/36296 could help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SaveVerbatim` and the insert the code with `\BUseVerbatim` as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[10pt, t]{beamer}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{SaveVerbatim}{1a}
Some code here 1a
\end{SaveVerbatim}
\begin{SaveVerbatim}{1b}
Some code here 1b
\end{SaveVerbatim}
\begin{SaveVerbatim}{2a}
Some code here 2a
\end{SaveVerbatim}
\begin{SaveVerbatim}{2b}
Some code here 2b
\end{SaveVerbatim}

\begin{frame}[fragile, plain]
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][.8\textheight]{0.45\textwidth}\strut
  \begin{onlyenv}<1->%
    \BUseVerbatim{1a}
  \end{onlyenv}
  \begin{onlyenv}<3->%
    \BUseVerbatim{1b}
  \end{onlyenv}
\end{minipage}}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][.8\textheight]{0.45\textwidth}\strut
  \begin{onlyenv}<2->%
    \BUseVerbatim{2a}
  \end{onlyenv}
  \begin{onlyenv}<4->%
    \BUseVerbatim{2b}
  \end{onlyenv}
\end{minipage}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note the `\strut`s and `%`'s added to avoid unwanted spacing.